# Updating of the users passwords of the security.yaml file

Tags: symfony4

I configured the **config/packages/security.yaml** file as it said [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#security-authorization)  with hardcoded users as you can see:

```yaml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:
                        password: ryanpass
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    admin:
                        password: kitten
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
    access_control:
        # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I lauched the symfony command:
`php bin/console security:encode-password` in order to encode the password with the bcrypt algorithm. By this way, I will normally see the changes in the **config/packages/security.yaml** file, something like:

```yaml
users:
    ryan:
        password: $2a$12$LCY0MefVIEc3TYPHV9SNnuzOfyr2p/AXIGoQJEDs4am4JwhNz/jli
        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
    admin:
        password: $2a$12$cyTWeE9kpq1PjqKFiWUZFuCRPwVyAZwm4XzMZ1qPUFl7/flCM3V0G
        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
```

But after launching this command, the console is asking me to type a password:

```
Symfony Password Encoder Utility
================================

 Type in your password to be encoded:
 >
```

Can you explain me how to obtain the correct behavior?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It is not meant so literally. You have to manually type each password and convert it to hashed form with that command. In console you will see "Encoded password".

Comment: Yes, I did not understand like that. Thank you!